# Replacing Generic IGBT with CoPack IGBT

Tags: igbt

The IGBT of my induction cooker recently blown up and I have found it's FGA20S125P which is a 1250V 20A Shorted anode type IGBT. The datasheet is available [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fga20s125p-d.pdf).
However I couldn't find this IGBT model and overseas orders would take months to reach me at a reasonable cost.

I came across a different IGBT Called IRG4PH50UD which has almost same parameters (close enough I guess) from a local vendor. The datasheet is available [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRG4PH50UD-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153564871582327).

However this IGBT is mentioned as an **"UltraFast CoPack IGBT"** with a weird symbol as shown below.
[image]

I couldn't find much information what **"Copack IGBT"** means. It seems to be some kind of small improvement to existing IGBT technology. Could someone explain me what this term means?
Would I be possibly able to replace FGA20S125P with this IGBT? The datasheet parameters looks almost similar as far as my knowledge on IGBTs goes. Also please note that I have limited experience using IGBTs as well.

Comment: It's says what copack means right there on the front page in the third bullet point in the feature list.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks, I was confused by the weird symbol and never though it's something simple as that.

Comment: Update: I have replaced FGA20S125P with IRG4PH50UD and my induction cooker came back to life. No magic smoke :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoPack means the avalanche diode and IGBT are packaged together and both are rated at 20A continuously. (or 16A/24A in the case of your Infineon example)

You can inspect some datasheets to check for crossovers.

https://www.trustedparts.com/en/similar-parts/on-semiconductor/FGA20S120M

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it's something simple as that. I guess both igbts should be compatible enough for my purpose then.